# Login to a website with a radio button using python's request module

Tags: python, python-2.7, post, python-requests, basic-authentication

I am trying to log in to a Website and retrieve some date therein. I tried the following code:

```
from requests import session  

payload = {  
    r"Login1$UserName": "myusername",  
    r"Login1$Password": "thepassword",  
    r"Login1$RadioButtonList_Type": "Tuna"  
}  

with session() as s:
    s.post("http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/", data=payload)
    req = s.get("http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/Member/CatchReportTuna.aspx")
    print(req.text)
```

But the result shows that I am not logged in the site. And I would like to know why the above code failed, and how to login into [the website](http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/).
I am new to parsing data from the sites, so any opinion is sincerely welcomed, thanks in advance.

P.S. The name `r"Login1$RadioButtonList_Type"` refers to the name of a radio button on that website, and I would like to set its value to `Tuna`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key problem is that there are **hidden ASP.NET form fields** that should also be *a part of the payload*. This means that you first need to make a `GET` request to a page and parse the hidden `input` field values. Also, you need to provide a `User-Agent` header. Using [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) for html-parsing part:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from requests import session

payload = {  
    r"Login1$UserName": "myusername",  
    r"Login1$Password": "thepassword",  
    r"Login1$RadioButtonList_Type": "Tuna",
    r"Login1$LoginButton": u"登入"
}  
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_2) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.111 Safari/537.36'}

with session() as s:
    s.headers = headers
    response = s.get('http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/')

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    for input_name in ['__EVENTTARGET', '__EVENTARGUMENT', '__VIEWSTATE', '__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR', '__EVENTVALIDATION']:
        payload[input_name] = soup.find('input', {'name': input_name}).get('value', '')

    s.post("http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/", data=payload)

    req = s.get("http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/Member/CatchReportTuna.aspx")
    print(req.content)
```

Just FYI, you could have also used the following tools to submit the form without being explicitly worried about the hidden form fields:

- [`mechanize`](http://wwwsearch.sourceforge.net/mechanize/)
- [`MechanicalSoup`](https://github.com/hickford/MechanicalSoup)
- [`robobrowser`](https://github.com/jmcarp/robobrowser)

---

Another option, would be to mimic a real you by automating a real browser through [`selenium`](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/):

```
from selenium import webdriver

login = "mylogin"
password = "mypassword"

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/')

# fill the form
driver.find_element_by_id('Login1_UserName').send_keys(login)
driver.find_element_by_id('Login1_Password').send_keys(password)
driver.find_element_by_id('Login1_RadioButtonList_Type_0').click()

# submit
driver.find_element_by_id('Login1_LoginButton').click()

driver.get('http://elogbook.ofdc.org.tw/Member/CatchReportTuna.aspx')
print driver.page_source
```

Comment: I still cannot login in the site. Perhaps I should give up this approach using requests module...

Comment: @awllower well, this is what I've spotted, may be there is smth else wrong -  but I don't have credentials to try.

Comment: I see. If I use some other tool, such as MechanicalSoup, I don't have to worry about those things? Also, still thanks for the attention. :)

Comment: @awllower give it a try. Well, I have one more option to suggest - would you be okay with automating a real browser for the purpose of this task? If yes, I'll give you a sample.

Comment: That would be fine, and I would like to see a sample. Thanks very much.

Comment: @awllower I've also found a problem in the first approach - you should give it an another try also.

Comment: Yes, the first aproach now works! It seems that the login button must be clicked! Thanks for the great help, and I shall study for a while how selenium works. Anyway, thanks.